# Strange behaviour of Eclipse to access variable in the same method

Tags: java, android

hy!

I added a library to my project and i want to use it in my class

Code:

```
import com.jjoe64.graphview.*;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import greendroid.app.GDActivity;

public class StatisticActivity extends GDActivity {

    GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
              new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
              , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
              , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
              , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
    });

    GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
          this // context
          , "GraphViewDemo");

    graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // can't access that variable

    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    //layout.addView(graphView);
}
```

My problem is that i can't get access to the variables. when i type in "graphView." and see what the auto-suggest says no variables from my class are in it.

GraphView Class:

http://www.sourcepod.com/dknqvl76-5923

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and third commented-out lines are invalid syntax, and that's probably the issue here. Only member declarations can appear at the top level of the class. *Statements* like

```
graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries);
```

can only appear inside a method or initialization block. Eclipse won't recognize `graphView` as a variable at that point in your code; only a class name would be valid, so that's how it is interpreted.

Comment: @test123123 Welcome to Java. There is no "normal" code. Everything should be in methods.

Comment: THX(i was too lazy) it was a stressfull day